# What is the equivalent in MS Word for Row() function?

Tags: ms-word

I need an MS Word formula or field that returns the current row number within a table. something like the Row() function in Excel.

Comment: Word has nothing like Excel's Row() function. Perhaps you need to embed an Excel worksheet in your document. Alternatively, to see how to do a wide range of calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party

Comment: I found this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-formula-in-a-word-or-outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27 which mentions the following:

To refer to…  
The row that contains the formula

…use this reference style
R

Can anybody highlight how to use such a reference? 

Note: I have the first column in the table an MS Word field with sequence, so if the reference works I can get the value of that field.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/788531/in-ms-word-2016-table-how-to-get-the-current-row-n.html. Please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was posted as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71627932/what-is-the-equivalent-in-ms-word-for-row-function/71647234#comment126591753_71627932) from [macropod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9170274):

> Word has nothing like Excel's Row() function. Perhaps you need to embed an Excel worksheet in your document. Alternatively, to see how to do a wide range of calculations in Word, check out my Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial, at: msofficeforums.com/word/… or gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party